# Trapezium span with CSS

Tags: css, html

Is there any way I could draw a trapezium span thing with text in it? Doesn't matter if the corners are rounded, in fact, I'd prefer it if they were. [I know how to make an oval/circle with border-radius](http://jsfiddle.net/NaAYe/), but I'm stuck on the trapezium. Help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it pure css using `pseudo-elements` and `skew` css property with support `border-radius`: [demo on dabblet.com](http://dabblet.com/gist/2868194)
http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/9683/eedea21cb3bc438fb33c80c.png

**html:**  `<span>Trapezium</span>`
**css:**

```
span {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;

    /* custom sizes */
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

span:before,
span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

span:before {
    transform: skew(25deg);
    left: 25px;
}

span:after {
    transform: skew(-25deg);
    right: 25px;
    left: auto;
}
```

#### **UPD:** [demo without `pseudo-elements`](http://dabblet.com/gist/2894280)

Comment: Just asking, I know I should avoid it, but is there any way to do this inline (so without pseudoclasses)?

Comment: @Bluefire ‘inline’ does you mean inline styles? Inline styles not effect to `:before` and `:after`. Pseudo-elements are using in example nor pseudoclasses(:hover, :active, :not etc)

Comment: Fine, pseudoelements :O I'm still sure you can't use them inline. I mean, instead of `myelement { color: black; }` embedded in the head, I need something like `<myelement style="color:black;"></myelement>`.

Comment: It is possible to use `inline css` if you will change pseudo-elements to inner `div` (one `div` for `:before`, and one for ':after') and will apply to them the appropriate styles from pseudo-elements styles. Do you understand my explanation (my english can be poor), or better to show an example?

Comment: I kinda do, and your English is fine (I'm Russian too :D) but knowing me, I'll probably get something wrong, so if you can, an example would be great!

Comment: i added demo w/o pseudo-elements to answer. Simple apply inline styles to them  by yourself, it will work for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12302/discussion-between-vladimir-starkov-and-bluefire)

Answer (score 0):

Use this css code

```
span {display:block;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it once, think it was something like this:

http://jsbin.com/ebejip/